# Floating Bars in Matplotlib Pyplot Bar Graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working on a graph with a really large range and I'm finding that the bars float off the axis. How can I stop this? This is an example I cooked up with the tutorial since my data is gotten from reading from a ton of files. This illustrates the problem I'm having. I gave the stds and means a big range like in my data.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 5
menMeans = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27,43,444,44)
menStd =   (2, 3, 4, 1, 2,43,4,33)

ind = np.arange(8)  # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, menMeans, width, color='r', yerr=menStd)

womenMeans = (25, 32, 34, 25,322,3,443,3)
womenStd =   (3, 5, 2, 3, 3,32,33,322)
rects2 = ax.bar(ind+width, womenMeans, width, color='y', yerr=womenStd)

# add some
ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
ax.set_xticks(ind+width)
ax.set_xticklabels( ('G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5','K','K','Z') )

ax.legend( (rects1[0], rects2[0]), ('Men', 'Women') )

def autolabel(rects):
    # attach some text labels
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height, '%d'%int(height),
                ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)

plt.show()
```

Comment: what is the mean of "the bars float off the axis", I didn't see any problem by runing the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add limits to the y-axis:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 5
menMeans = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27,43,444,44)
menStd =   (2, 3, 4, 1, 2,43,4,33)

ind = np.arange(8)  # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, menMeans, width, color='r', yerr=menStd)

womenMeans = (25, 32, 34, 25,322,3,443,3)
womenStd =   (3, 5, 2, 3, 3,32,33,322)
rects2 = ax.bar(ind+width, womenMeans, width, color='y', yerr=womenStd)

# add some
ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
ax.set_xticks(ind+width)
ax.set_xticklabels( ('G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5','K','K','Z') )

ax.legend( (rects1[0], rects2[0]), ('Men', 'Women') )
ax.set_ylim(0)

def autolabel(rects):
    # attach some text labels
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height, '%d'%int(height),
                ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)

plt.show()
```

The line `ax.set_ylim(0)` does the trick.